# Add active class to li a jquery

Tags: jquery, class

I'm trying to remove and set an active class for a list item every time it's clicked. I can't understand where is the mistake. Thanks in advance

```html
<ul id="active-menu" class="ul">
  <li class="menu_li">
    <a id="li1" class="blogname active" href="index.php">
      <?=$m1?>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu_li">
    <a id="li3" class="blogname" href="work.php">
      <?=$m3?>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu_li">
    <a id="li4" class="blogname" href="clients.php">
      <?=$m4?>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu_li">
    <a id="li2" class="blogname" href="blog.php">
      <?=$m2?>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu_li">
    <a id="li5" class="blogname" href="contact.php">
      <?=$m5?>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('#active-menu').on('click', 'a', function() {
  $('#active-menu a.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Is the link click actually causing a new page to be loaded? If so, that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you need, you don't need the listener you had for the a tag click, instead, you have to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get the current page name, and activate the a tag according to it using condition for adding active class.

Comment: thank you for the answer: now the active class works as i want, but a href is not going from page to page, it stays in the same page(

Comment: What is the purpose of adding the active class if it is going to display really briefly if you do not preventDefault ?  You are going to go to a new page soon after it is clicked ?  Maybe I don't understand the question, of you want to load content via AJAX.

Comment: I just want to show the user in witch page is he at the moment: for example, when the site is loaded, homepage link is active(color is red), so, i want,  when user click's  on another link, hompage shuld become passive like others, and clicked page become active. That's a purpose i would like to do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you include this piece of HTML into every PHP file you have, as a fixed menu element.

So, anytime someone clicks on the menu links, they are basically navigated to another page (unless you load the links via ajax - which doesn't seem to be the case). In this case, there's no need to add/remove the active class via jQuery - actually it won't have any effect too as elements' states will not be kept when you navigate away.

As pointed out in the first answer, you'll need to check which page was loaded on the first go, and then add the "active" class on the menu item if necessary.

This could be handled by first determining the active page:

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$active_page = "";

if (strpos($request, 'blog.php') !== false) {
   $active_page = "blog";   
} else if (strpos($request, 'contact.php') !== false {
   $active_page = "contact";
}
```

... and so on. Then when you're listing the menu items, you can check whether they are the active item and if so, you can add the active class, like:

```
<ul id="active-menu" class="ul">
  <li class="menu_li">
    <a class="blogname <?=$active_page == 'blog' ? 'active' : ''?>"  href="blog.php">
      Menu item text
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu_li">
    <a class="blogname <?=$active_page == 'contact' ? 'active' : ''?>"  href="contact.php">
      Menu item text
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```